# Why does a multisignature wallet in mist only require one signature?

Tags: transactions, mist, multisignature, signature

I've created one new contract wallet from an account in mist and this account is supposed to required two signatures. When I test it to send some coins, it asks me to enter one password from one account only and doesn't ask me for the other account. Is it normal?

I thought all this was for more secure things?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default wallet contract has a threshold for "high value" transactions that require multiple signatures, whereas "low value" transactions need only a single signature. This value is specified on deployment.